How to Prevent Parent Container Scrollbar When Showing Dropdown in Tailwind and DaisyUI?
I have an HTML template that uses Tailwind CSS and DaisyUI. Here is the code snippet:
<div class="flex h-32 w-48 items-center overflow-y-scroll">
  <span class="overflow-hidden truncate whitespace-nowrap p-4">Apple</span>
  <details class="dropdown m-4">
    <summary class="btn m-1">...</summary>
    <ul class="dropdown-content menu z-[2] w-52 rounded-box bg-base-200 p-2">
      <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </details>
</div>

The issue I'm encountering is that when I click the button to show the dropdown menu, a scrollbar appears in the parent container. I want to prevent the parent container from showing the scrollbar when the dropdown is displayed. How can I achieve this?
Tailwind Playground Link: https://play.tailwindcss.com/K6ruW2ajJr
Any help on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!
What I've Tried:

I have tried adjusting the z-index of the dropdown menu.
I have attempted to change the overflow properties of the parent container.

Additional Information:

I'm using Tailwind CSS and DaisyUI.
The dropdown should appear without causing the parent container to scroll.


Are you trying to get the dropdown to go outside the bounds of the parent container so that the parent container does not change shape at all? Or do you want the parent container to resize to fit the dropdown?

Thanks @JHeth for looking into it.
Yes I want to go outside or above the bounds of parent container so that parent container don't change shape.
After some research I find popper js which may solve my problem.
Thank you.

I came for a different problem but solved yours... The solution to your problem is to just replace the

overflow-y-scroll

to

overflow-visible

and the ul will appear above the bounds of the original parent div.
Hope that helps.

If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - From Review
